# What are the best way to display text from database using MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, refresh

I have created a MVC application its working fine. I have created a view which have few viewdata variables. I am filling these with my database values, and they are updated in loop.
This method take 40-50 seconds to display actual page contents. So is there any other way to display the contents which we get till now and do refresh it till all contents are loaded.

Please let me know how can I refresh the page ?

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: More details; this question is not going to get answered as it stands, because nobody will have any idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is very typical nowadays. The most popular solution is to use AJAX and show data as they are retrieved.